# How Can I Implement Custom Previous/Next Buttons Over MPMovieplayer?

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, mpmoviewcontroller

I have implemented a listing of videos in a `UITableView`. When I touch on a particular video then the video plays in an `MPMovieplayer`.  Now, I want to make it so that if I touch on a next button, then the next video in the `UITableView` will play. How can I implement this?

Comment: I think you need to start giving credit where credit is due before getting anymore help here.

Answer (score 1):

- Search for "MPMoviePlayer overlay" on stack overflow
- Put an overlay over the movie with a previous and next button on it.
- Make the buttons target methods that control `MPMoviePlayer`.